# Firefox doesn't show silverlight controls

Tags: silverlight, firefox, windowless

I have a silverlight application in which I am using the windowless property to show text .
Silverlight Plugin Size is 1000*2000, I Have a button (siverlight control) on the Top.
I am showing some html text using DIV real time. Its working fine.

My Silverlight Plugin & DIV both style property is= "position:absolute'.

This application is working fine in IE, but When I run this application in Firefox Button doesn't dsiplayed.

Please let me know whats a issue with Firefox ?

Thanks in advance, 
Laxmilal

Comment: What size is your containing div? Are you hiding the div and then showing it? (FFox used to have an issue with this, dunno if it still does). If you right click where the control should be, do you get the silverlight context menu?

Comment: My DIV size is 1000*2000, and updating height realtime based on HTML conetnts.

Comment: Does it work fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera?

Comment: Its working fine in Crome, Safari.

Comment: Sounds more like a variation in HTML markup/css handling than a Silverlight issue to me.  Try using a similar markup and position styles but use an Img (or better yet something else the uses object) instead of Silverlight plugin.  Does that look ok?

Answer (score 0):

In your html, specify following code in CSS

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
min-width: 800px;
min-height: 600px;
}

#silverlightControlHost {
height: 100%;}
```

Then in the body

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="SOURCE OF YOUR XAP"/>
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                <!--Your other para-->
</object>
```